# how to use localized strings in flutter's main app

Tags: flutter, flutter-intl

I am new to Flutter and I am building a localized app using the flutter-intl plugin.
I've declared a "Title" string in the .arb file for my locales.
My program is trying to use this string as follows:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        S.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
      title: S.current.Title,
```

I've tried using `S.current.Title` and `S.of(context).Title`, and in both cases when the program starts I get the following error message:
[image]

When I change the title property to `title: 'my title'`, the app performs hot-reload and the error screen disappears. When I change the title back to `title: S.current.Title` the localized title is displayed with no error.

This behavior has been consistently confirmed with Android-studio and VS-Code with web and Android targets.

I guess it has to do with Flutter's initialization sequence. What is the proper way to use localized strings as properties in the MaterialApp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documentation suggests:

> To provide a localized title instead, use [onGenerateTitle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp/onGenerateTitle.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

import 'config/languages/localizations.dart';
import 'config/languages/localizations_delegate.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        localizationsDelegates: const [
          MyLocalizationsDelegate(),
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: const [
          Locale('en', ''),
          Locale('de', ''),
        ],
        onGenerateTitle: (context) => MyLocalizations.of(context)?.title ?? '',
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      );
}
```

localizations.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyLocalizations {
  MyLocalizations(this.locale);

  final Locale locale;

  static MyLocalizations? of(BuildContext context) =>
      Localizations.of<MyLocalizations>(context, MyLocalizations);

  static languages() => _localizedValues.keys.toList();

  String get title => _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]!['title']!;

  static const _localizedValues = <String, Map<String, String>>{
    'en': {
      'title': 'Hello World',
    },
    'de': {
      'title': 'Hallo Welt',
    },
  };
}
```

localizations_delegate.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'localizations.dart';

class MyLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<MyLocalizations> {
  const MyLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) =>
      MyLocalizations.languages().contains(locale.languageCode);

  @override
  Future<MyLocalizations> load(Locale locale) =>
      SynchronousFuture<MyLocalizations>(MyLocalizations(locale));

  @override
  bool shouldReload(MyLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MaterialApp(
  // title: 'your title',
  onGenerateTitle: (context) => 
      S.maybeOf(context) != null ? S.current.title : 'your default title',
);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**